# Find what values are not in multiple columns

Tags: db2, db2-midrange

I need to find what "Codes" from column "RMS_CODE" and column "RMS_ALT1_Cde" are not being used in the Child # (starting in position 6 for a length of 4) column within the "APC_Spec" number. I tried using the sql in the image provided, but it only looks in the row and doesn't check the whole column within the "APC_Spec" requirement. Can anyone suggest a method to check which codes are not being used per "APC_Spec" in the Child column #?

[image: SQL Example]

Comment: Please read why you [should not post screenshots of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with tRMS_CODE as 
   (SELECT DISTINCT RMS_CODE FROM RMS_Table)
   , tRMS_ALT1_Cde as 
   (SELECT DISTINCT RMS_ALT1_Cde FROM RMS_Table)
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM RMS_Table
WHERE 
   SUBSTR(CHILD,6,4) NOT IN (SELECT * FROM tRMS_CODE) AND 
   SUBSTR(CHILD,6,4) NOT IN (SELECT * FROM tRMS_ALT1_Cde) AND 
   APC_Spec='36559'
```

Comment: Thank you, it does work. the second with gets rejected, but after putting a comma in and removing the second with it worked. thanks